# using str() function as variable name

Tags: python-3.x

I'm newbie in python.
As I learned, `str(123)` returns the string format of value `123` which is `'123'`
but what if we have a variable named `str`, how can I call the `str` function?

```
In[2]: str(123)
Out[2]: '123'
In[3]: str='hello world'
In[4]: str(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x625/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-6d97c31da288>", line 1, in <module>
    str(123)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How can I call `str()` function again?

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable. However, you can still get to it using `import builtins` and then `builtins.str`.

Answer (score 2):

You still can access it:

```
import builtins
builtins.str(123)
```

Don't use `str` as a variable name, it is a keyword.

Comment: This doesn't work in interactive mode or from `__main__`. If you really want to use the module that contains all built-in names, that's `import __builtin__` (no s) on Python 2, or `import builtins` on Python 3.

Comment: edit my answer please or post a better one

Answer (score 1):

Just don't call your variables `str`.

If you made a mistake in interactive mode and need to get rid of a variable you picked a bad name for, you can do `del str`, but don't do that in an actual program.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, so you mean there is no way around that to call actual function name rather than variable if we use function as a variable name?

Comment: @user3375740: This isn't C#. Functions and variables don't live in separate namespaces. There are technically workarounds for calling a built-in when you have a variable shadowing it, but they're far clumsier than just picking a different name.

Comment: there is a way to access builtin functions using `globals()` or using [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable name `str='hello world'` collides withe the function `str`.

Just pick another name to your variable.